Abelian extensions of number fields generated by torsion points of elliptic curve (as analogy to Lubin-Tate theory)
According to a remark from wikipedia the motivation of Lubin-Tate theory arose from the analogy to the way in which elliptic curves $E/K$  over a number field $K$ with extra endomorphisms (ie those posessing complex multiplication CM) are used to give abelian extensions.
From level of exhaustivity (see below what I mean by this precisely), how "close" is this analogy? The loose connection is that in both cases we use the torsion points of an "auxilary object" (some $1$-dim  formal group in LT-theory, resp a elliptic curve with CM ) to cover up certain - more precisely the Abelian totally ramified - exitensions of the given local field - feel free to think of $p$-adics $\Bbb Q_p$ -, resp. Abelian extensions of the base field $K$ of elliptic curve $E$ choosen to be a number field.
( to make it more precise, jump to next paragraph or read @KConrad's comment below)
But note that the Lubin-Tate theory is not a gadget to cover up all finite extension of a local field, but only the totally ramified extensions (for $\Bbb Q_p$ that would the $p$-part)  via adjoining certain torsion points of certain $1$-dim formal group to obtain family (... more precisely a tower) of certain extensions $K_{\pi, n}$, which contain totally unramified Ab. fin. extensions. And the pun is:
It does it exhaustively for the totally ramified part in the sense that for every fin Ab. totally ramified ext'n $L/ \Bbb Q_p $ there exist a $K_{\pi, n((L)}$ obtained by adjoining appropriatetorsion points of the associated $1$-dim formal group to $\Bbb Q_p$ which contains $L$. And in such way  all finite totally ramified extensions can be exhausted, exactly in same vein - of course only on level of analogy - as in Weber's Theorem the cyclotomic extensions exhaust fin Abelian extensions of $\Bbb Q$. So one could phrase it as slogan that  Lubin-Tate theory is exhaustive wrt the totally ramified part.
Rmk: The extensions $K_{\pi, n}$ are called non surprisingly the Lubin-Tate extensions.
Now comming back to the analogy to the torsion points of elliptic curve.
Question: How "exhaustive" - in admitedly rather vague sense above - is the procedure of generating Abelian field extensions of the function field $K$ of its elliptic curve via the torsion points?
(practically, one adjoints the coordinate entries of the considered torsion points to the base number field)
Ie, which finite Abelian extensions can be covered up as subextension exactly in same vein as in Lubin-Tate, resp Weber's result by Lubin-Tate, resp. cyclotomic extensions.
As below comments suggest, it's highly too optimistic to expect that with this method really all finite Abelian extensions be exhaused like in case of Weber's theorem for Abelian extensions of $\Bbb Q$.
But can one say on what kind of Abelian extensions of $K$ can be exhaused by this  torsion points construction? Do these share some number theoretic common properties?
Subsequent question: There are some qualitative results for elliptic curves with CM or without it, and how goes CM into it?
Say, what fails precisely if the consided elliptic curve would not have CM? (ie the endomorphism ring equals $\Bbb Z$) What would exactly break down?
Also it appears that to have gain some qualitative results one resricts to a rather "narrow" class of fields& extensions, eg totally imaginary quadratic extensions of totally real fields (compare with a comment below).
This suggeat that the torsion points "know" just a little about the Abelian extensions of a given number field, in contrast to biased expectations influenced by Weber's result.
So the metaquestion (admittedly very vague) can be phrased as: What amount of information the torsion points of elliptic curve $E/K$ carry about Abelian Galois theory of $K$? What is "plausible" to expect?

I think you have to be careful in describing the extensions gotten by L & T: these are abelian ramified extensions only.

A vague question deserves a vague answer. If $L/L^{+}$ is a totally imaginary CM extension, one can hope to construct by these methods the part of $G^{\mathrm{ab}}_L$ on which $\mathrm{Gal}(L/L^{+})$ acts by $-1$.

@user491858: what do you mean by subfield $L^+$ of $L$; what does the upper plus indicate? Is it a kind special subfied? (have to admit that I never saw such notation with $+$ in this context before before). Does this notation just serve to distinguish it from bigger field $L$? is it a formal symbol to indicate that the considered extension is totally imaginary CM?

$L^+$ is the totally real subfield of a CM field $L$.  Alternatively $L^+$ is an arbitrary totally real field and $L$ is a totally imaginary quadratic extension.

You write "it generates in that way all finite totally ramified extensions. So [it] is exhaustive wrt the ramified part."  You meant to say at the end "wrt the totally ramified part", but keep in mind that totally ramified extensions (in a common field) are not well-behaved under composites: if $L$ and $L'$ are totally ramified over $K$, $LL'$ need not be: when $K$ has odd residue field characteristic, it has 3 quadratic extensions (2 tot. ram. and 1 unr.), and the composite of the 2 quadratic tot. ramified extns is not tot. ramified, since the composite contains the quad. unramified extn.

(contd.) Each finite tot. ram. abelian extn. of $K$ (the quadratic extns in my last comment are abelian) is contained in a Lubin-Tate extn $K_{\pi,n}$ for some uniformizer $\pi$ of $K$ and $n \geq 1$. Since $K_{\pi,n}\subset K_{\pi,n+1}$ for all $n$, the $K_{\pi,n}$'s as $n$ (but not $\pi$) varies are as nice as $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_{p^n})$, but random totally ramified abelian extensions of $K$ with increasing degree aren't nice under field composites. The union of all $K_{\pi,n}$ as $n$ varies is a complement to the max. unram. extn. of $K$ in $K^{\rm ab}$, but it is not a canonical complement.

@KConrad: Thanks for elaborating the "mechanism" behind Lubin-Tate theory precisely, I tried to implement it in the question. But the nature of the question is of course confessedly very vague, since I'm to sure which common number theoretic features the fields obtained by adjoining the (coords) of $n$
-torsion points of the ell curve $E/K$
to the base should share, in order to ponder about for which type of Abelian extensions these should naturally "serve as container" in analogy to Lubin-Tate resp Weber's philosophy (presumably, if I understood it correctly)

@KConrad: one nitpick: how can one see in situation above that the are two quadratic totally ramifided extensions? Say $\pi$ is a uniformizer of $K$, then one comes obviously from Eisenstein pol $X^2-\pi$ (or more abstractly via Galois corresp, $\text{Gal}(K_{\pi}/K) \cong \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$, we can find a unique(!) subgroup of index $2$ inside $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}/U_1 \cong \Bbb F_q^*$ where we exploit here that the characteristic of residue field is assumed to be odd. But where is the "other" quadratic totally ramif ext? Guess: can we produce the other by choosing different

uniformizer $\pi'$ and construct the extension as before with Eisenstein pol, but for $\pi'$? If that's the right approach, how can we decide if two uniformizers $\pi, \pi'$ give same or different quadratic tot ramif ext's? A naive guess: These give different ext iff for relation $u \cdot \pi = \pi'$ the unit $u$ contains the lifted $2$-root from residue as factor? Is it correct; how to prove it formally? (...by the way, this would also explain why $L'L/K$ cannot be totally ramified due to this $2$-root $\zeta_2 = \pi'/ \pi$...

A (totally) ramified quadratic extension is gotten by adjoining the square root of any uniformizer: $K(\sqrt{\pi u})$ where $u$ runs through the units. Since $K(\sqrt{\alpha})=K(\sqrt{\beta})$ if and only if $\alpha/\beta$ is a square in $K$, and $(\pi u)/(\pi u')=u/u'$, all the quadratic ramified extensions occur as $u$ runs over representatives of $\mathcal O_K^\times/(\mathcal O_K^\times)^2$, which has order $2$: it's represented by $1$ and $r$ where $r$ is any unit that is not a square in the residue field. When $K=\mathbf Q_5$, its quad. ram. extns are $K(\sqrt{5})$ and $K(\sqrt{10})$.
